# How to create an infinite horizontal scroll animation using Qwik framework?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, css-animations, qwik

I am trying to create a web page that has an infinite horizontal scroll animation using Qwik framework. I have added the CSS part, but I don’t know how to add the JavaScript part.

`here is my code:` https://stackblitz.com/edit/qwik-starter-v5hp1x?file=src%2Froutes%2Findex.tsx

I am expecting this type of result

`you can see it on codepen:` https://codepen.io/zeronicola/pen/eYZddOd